# Selecting the correct element of a combo box in selenium

Tags: selenium

I have an on click selection list with check boxes and I'm trying to use select to get at a checkbox value but my code fails to find the element.
My code so far is:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/seiki-live-status-andon-component/div/div[1]/div/button")).click();` //Clicks on the a button to bring up the drop dox menu screen.

Select select=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/seiki-live-status-andon-component/seiki-select-resources-modal/seiki-modal/ngx-smart-modal/div/div/div/div/div[2]/resource-and-reporting-group-selector/div/ng-select/ng-dropdown-panel/div")));
```

here is The Screenshot of the inspect.

[image]

I'm I going about this the wrong way?
I've spent half the day using different elements, but without success.
Any advise would be greatly apricated.

Answer (score 0):

I was going about it the wrong way.
I have just simply used click for each step.
e.g.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/seiki-live-status-andon-component/div/div[1]/div/button")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/seiki-live-status-andon-component/seiki-select-resources-modal/seiki-modal/ngx-smart-modal/div/div/div/div/div[2]/resource-and-reporting-group-selector/div/ng-select")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/seiki-live-status-andon-component/seiki-select-resources-modal/seiki-modal/ngx-smart-modal/div/div/div/div/div[2]/resource-and-reporting-group-selector/div/ng-select/ng-dropdown-panel/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/input")).click();       

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/seiki-live-status-andon-component/seiki-select-resources-modal/seiki-modal/ngx-smart-modal/div/div/div/div/div[1]")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/seiki-live-status-andon-component/seiki-select-resources-modal/seiki-modal/ngx-smart-modal/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div/button")).click();
```